# How do I convert an array of decimal values to a MAC address in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, decimal, pack, unpack

I have an array of strings, and each item is a base 10 decimal value which needs to be converted to base 16 equivalents:

Input:

```
a = ["23", "137", "44", "30", "38", "2"]
```

Output:

```
#=> ["17", "89", "2c", "1e", "26", "02"]
```

Ideally I need to what the array really represents, which is a 48 byte MAC address:

```
#=> "17892c1e2602" or "17:89:2c:1e:26:02"
```

I tried and failed with both `pack` and `unpack` and:

```
a.map { |i| i.to_s(16) }
```

results in `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`.

Any help with conversion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = ["23", "137", "44", "30", "38", "2"]

a.map(&:to_i).map { |i| i.to_s(16).rjust(2, '0') }.join ':' 
#=> "17:89:2c:1e:26:02"
```

*UPD* As suggested by Cary in comments, there is no need in two subsequent `map`s:

```
a.map { |s| s.to_i.to_s(16).rjust(2, '0') }.join ':' 
#=> "17:89:2c:1e:26:02"
```

Comment: This does the job: `["232", "137", "44", "30", "37", "18"].map(&:to_i).map {|i| i.to_s(16).rjust(2,'0') }.join ':'` and in testing is the quickest

Comment: @CarySwoveland indeed, thanks, the answer is updated.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have deleted my comment, as it provided context. It was, " 
Good one, mudsie. Two maps in a row is rarely a good thing. Consider combining them. "

Comment: @mudasobwa I've extracted the array into a variable and replaced `do ... end` with a more terse `{ ... }` - hope you don't mind :-)

Comment: @Stefan absolutely, feel free to change anything, including my nickname :) BTW, when I do mind, I reject edits.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I took your advice and combined the map's to this: `["23","137","44","30","37","18"].map {|i| i.to_i.to_s(16).rjust(2,'0') }.join ':'` which outputs as needed

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Kernel#sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) formatting with an `x` field type:

```
a = ["23", "137", "44", "30", "38", "2"]

"%02x"*a.size % a
  #=> "17892c1e2602"
```

The steps:

```
"%02x"*a.size % a
  #=> "%02x"*6 % ["23", "137", "44", "30", "38", "2"]
  #   "%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x" % ["23", "137", "44", "30", "38", "2"]
  #=> "17892c1e2602"
```

In `"%02x"`:

- % means `sprintf` formatting follows
- the field type `x` means to "convert argument [an integer or a string] as a hexadecimal number"
- `2` is the field width
- `0` means to pad with zeroes rather than spaces

To insert colons:

```
(["%02x"]*a.size).join(':') % a
  #=> "17:89:2c:1e:26:02"
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jesse. I had noticed that and also that I could simplify.

Comment: This does it: `"#{'%02x:'*["232", "137", "44", "30", "37", "18"].size}".gsub(/:$/,"") % ["232", "137", "44", "30", "37", "18"].map(&:to_i)
`

Comment: Yes, @Tyler, but beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Just pass the string array to `sprintf`, you don't need `map(&:to_i)`

Comment: The last example could be written as `a.map { '%02x' }.join(':') % a`

Comment: @Stefan I thought I had tried the first and got a complaint, but not so. Curiously, in "The steps:", which I tested, I had forgotten `.map(&:to_i)`. Have edited to include both your suggestions. Alas, I am but a scribe.

Comment: In my previous revision I ended with "My answer benefitted greatly from @Stefan's wisdom." I, like, others, have often included attributions in answers, sometimes giving a modified answer and leaving my original answer. I'm leaning toward confining attributions to comments, and will edit out my original answer (which can still be viewed in the edit history, of course) if I prefer the revision. This is sort of like how books are written, where the end result is a product of many contributors, but I appreciate that credit is more important at SO (cont...)

Comment: ...so I think attributions and explanations of how the answer was changed should still be there, but I think comments are best for that, keeping the focus on the best answer that can be provided, regardless of who contributed what. This is perhaps not the place for a discussion of this matter, but if you want to offer your two cents, please do so.

Comment: I almost forgot. My answer benefitted greatly from @Stefan's wisdom. His suggestions, which I have incorporated in my answer, are discussed in the comments above.

Comment: This should probably be discussed on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/, would you post a question over there?

Comment: @CarySwoveland, not a matter of beauty, but a matter of processing speed. In my test of both working solutions the `.map()` solution ran 22% faster over 1000 iterations, and I need to process this over 13k times every 5 minutes so any time shaved is ideal

Comment: `(["%02x"]*a.size).join(':') % a`

Comment: Thanks, @mudasobwa, I did an edit: Readers: I formerly had `(a.map { |s| "%02x" }.join(':')) % a`, as suggested by...

Comment: ...@Stefan. I prefer mudsie's tweak. (You thought you could only cite one user per comment?)

Comment: @Tyler, you're right and `gsub!` would be faster yet. Another option would be to do it as a separate step `(s[-1] = '')`. It's still ugly, but no more ugly than the way I dealt with that pesky trailing semi-colon. What's ugly is having to do clean-up, which Stefan's/mudasobwa's suggestions avoid. Thanks for your comments. –

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for your input, I certainly learned a few things